# Patent holder died, no estate filed. Relatives may commercialize patents. The deceased sold shares and accepted loans?

Tags: intellectual-property, assignment, employee

Since 2010 recently deceased inventor (Pa. resident) received several significant US patents and filed several pending applications for US and international patents. No estate has been filed 8 months after death.  Inventor formed corporation, sold shares, solicited and accepted loans, hired staff with wage claims. Experiments by publicly traded US corps. and academic institutions have demonstrated viability of patent claims.

As a former employee, lender to the firm, shareholder in the Corporation and with potential claims for intellectual property created while an employee what are my options to discover actions taken to commercialize and/or transfer various rights and intellectual properties and to discover the actions being taken by surviving relatives, other employees, share holders and creditors?

Comment: This is not really in the scope of Ask Patents. I would re-ask it in Law SE. Patents are property and the disposition of them depends on state law.

Comment: It does have a patent law part, but that part needs more information. Are you an inventor on the patents?

Comment: This seems to me to be far too complex to answer here. I think you have no option other than consulting with a lawyer.